Nash equilibria of a "minority game"
An odd number $N \geq 3$ of players are playing a game - they bet on the outcome of a biased coin that comes up heads $p > \frac{1}{2}$ of the time, where $p$ is known to all of the players in advance.
Each player receives a payoff of $1$ if and only if they guess correctly and a minority of players bet on the outcome that they did. If they guess wrongly, or guess with the majority of players, they receive a payoff of $0$.
Players guess simultaneously and are looking to maximise only their own expected payoff.
Question: What are the set of Nash equilibria in mixed strategies? Is there a unique Nash equilibrium?

On a side note: never accept to play this game with unknown people, since they could  have agreed to bet every time (N-1)/2 of them on head and (N-1)/2 on tail!

@PietroMajer Hahah, the effect of coalitions on the game is also pretty interesting..

But this means that, if (by some reason or by chance) $(N-1)/2$ players adopt the strategy of betting always Heads, and  $(N-1)/2$ always Tails, the last player has no hope to win, whatever is their strategy.

Indeed, and that gives a continuum of asymmetric Nash equilibria. In addition there is a symmetric Nash equilibrium, where everyone chooses Heads with the same probability $q$. I think the condition for $q$ is that $pP(X<(N-1)/2)=(1-p)P(X>(N-1)/2)$ where $X\sim\text{Binomial}(N-1,q)$. Such $q$ is unique since the ratio between the LHS and the RHS is monotonic in $q$. Are there further asymmetric ones? I would guess not.

@JamesMartin I agree that these all give Nash equilibria, but why continuum? In order for it to be a genuine Nash equilibrium, they would have to deterministically bet heads/tails, and there are only finitely many such configurations of $N-1$ players.

Oh, right, one for every choice of strategy of the last player @JamesMartin

@JamesMartin :  For $N=3$, I think your formula gives  $ q={p-\sqrt{p(1-p)}\over 2p-1}$ whereas it should be $p\over\sqrt{1+p(1-p)}$ .

@StevenLandsburg I agree that's what my formula gives for $N=3$. It uses $p(1-q)^2=(1-p)q^2$. The RHS corresponds to the case where the coin is tails and your two "opponents" both bet heads, and the LHS corresponds to the case where the coin is heads and your two opponents both bet tails. For a Nash equilibrium I think we need those probabilities to be equal (otherwise you have an incentive to deviate in one direction or another). Your formula seems to give $q=1/\sqrt{5}$ when $p=1/2$, which seems strange. It should be $q=1/2$ when $p=1/2$, right? Nothing breaks the H/T symmetry in that case.

@JamesMartin:  Yes, I'd made an arithmetic mistake.  After correcting for it, I'm getting the same answer you are.  Sorry to trouble you.

Some thoughts about the  effect of coalitions. Assuming that the players are a priori indistinguishable, since at every toss at most  $\frac{N-1}2 $ of them can gain,  the maximum  total  average payoff is  $p \frac{N-1}2 $. An optimal strategy for a player, in whatever sense, is also optimal for every other one by symmetry, so  the optimal rational average payoff one can hope is $p \frac{N-1}{2N} $ (here “rational” means:  “assuming rational behaviour of opponents”).
If players can communicate, the evil coalition of players $P_1,\dots, P_{N-1}$ against player $P_N$, as said, is betting $\big( \frac{N-1}2 \text{ Heads}, \frac{N-1}2\text{ Tails}\big)$ every time, so that $P_N$ can do nothing but placing as bet Heads every time by revenge, so that the average total payoff of the others is minimised to $(1-p) \frac{N-1}2$.
However, in a less realistic world, players $P_1,\dots, P_{N-1}$ may agree  that each of them bets, cyclically with period $N$, Heads $\frac{N-1}2$ times and Tails $\frac{N+1}2$ times, in such a way that the corresponding total wager placed among them $N-1$, is   $\big( \frac{N-1}2 \text{ Heads}, \frac{N-1}2\text{ Tails}\big)$ for $\frac{N+1}2 $ times, and $\big(\frac{N-3}2 \text{ Heads}, \frac{N+1}2 \text{Tails}\big )$   for the remaining $\frac{N-1}2 $ times, and present the scheme to the last player $P_N$. This way $P_N$  can win nothing for $\frac{N+1}2$ times out of $N$, but has the opportunity of betting Heads for the remaining $\frac{N-1}2 $, ensuring the optimal rational average payoff of $p\frac{N-1}{2N}$ to everybody. In exchange, $P_N$ should only agree to bet Tail in the remaining  $\frac{N+1}2$ times out of $N$, which in any case are already lost for him/her. If $P_N$ does not agree, the coalition may pass to the evil strategy against him/her in retaliation.

A further question:  always assuming rational behaviour, how many virtuous  players are needed for a coalition that forces the other  ones to accept  a  common strategy  with  total  average payoff  $p\frac{N-1}{2}$?

You may want to consult the following paper:
https://pure.uvt.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/854659/dp2007-61.pdf
